# Detecting paste from clipboard in ToolStripTextBox (C#)

Tags: c#, clipboard, paste, wndproc

I need to detect if a user pastes text from the clipboard into a ToolStripTextBox. Therefore I've created a custom control which inherits from ToolStripTextBox. Then I wanted to override WndProc to catch WM_PASTE message, but I noticed that there is no WndProc to override. For the standard TextBox the described method works fine.

Any suggestion what to do to detect paste from clipboard on ToolStripTextBox?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a custom control that inherits the standard TextBox and implementing what you want from the ToolStripTextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WndProc` in `ToolStripTextBox` seems to be out of reach. I searched a bit out of curiosity and came across that answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4688745/168719

If using `ToolStripControlHost` is not an option, there are still other clever solutions for scenarioes requiring custom handling of WndProc:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/279168-toolstriptextbox-right-click

> Nicholas Paldino [.NET/C# MVP]
>
> I just noticed that. In order to get around this, you can get the
>   hosted TextBox by calling the TextBox property. Then, you should be
>   able to create a class derived from NativeWindow which overrides the
>   WndProc method to ignore the context menu message [or to intercept WM_PASTE, obviously...]
>        When you get the textbox property, get the handle, and assign the handle to your overridden NativeWindow class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the solution! Works perfect and is exactly what i searched for!

Comment: Thanks :) The full credit goes to original authors of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows[Windows forms / WPF] , you can use Clipboard to detect the data.

```
if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {

            richTextBox1.Paste();
            MessageBox.Show("You have data in clipboard")

            }
```

(Edited to include WPF)

Comment: Source: I borrowed code from my application here :  http://code.google.com/p/nepaliwikipediatranslator/source/browse/trunk/NepaliWikiPediaTranslator/FormMainWindowFunctions.cs?spec=svn197&r=197

Comment: Just to clarify: the application itself doesn't have to be a WinForm app, it can be WPF or whatever (console etc.). `Clipboard` just happens to be in WinForms namespace. But still you can very well use it in all types of applications. All it takes is adding a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`. Similarly, you can use Microsoft VB libraries from C# applications.

Comment: Yes, I use Windows.Forms. I know HOW to retrieve text from the clipboard but what I actually want is to detect WHEN a user tries to paste text from the clipboard.

Comment: Ok, I see..
However when a user tries to paste, The program would enter into the if block .. of 

if(...GetDataPresent()...)

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: He is wanting to know where to put your code. In what event would this code need to be to work like expected? TextChanged of the ToolStripTextBox?

Answer (score 0):

ToolStripTextBox is a host control containing a standard text box, you would need to do as you have described but replace the ToolStripTextBox.TextBox with your textbox, unfortunately it's a read only property.

So you'll need to derive a MyToolStripTextBox from ToolStripControlHost to be able to change the type of control it hosts.