# Custom Paint in ToolStripTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a problem about custom Paint method in class that inherit from ToolStripTextBox.
I need to draw an icon before ToolStripTextBox in ContextMenuStrip.

**FIRST ATTEMPT:**

```
 ContextMenuStrip CXstrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
 CXstrip.ImageList = [My defined list];
 var groupMenu = new ToolStripTextBox();
 groupMenu.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText;
 groupMenu.ImageIndex = 1;
```

*Failed :( Only textBox will Appear.*

**SECOND ATTEMPT:**

```
    public class ToolStripSpringTextBox : ToolStripTextBox {
      protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 50, 10);
      }
   }
```

*Paint is called, but he draw always standard textbox without my line (same of First Attempt)*

My question is why i cannot draw manually?
Why first (Logic) way to do this doesn't work like ToolStripMenuItem for example?

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customise rendering of a ToolStripTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762185/how-to-customise-rendering-of-a-toolstriptextbox)

Comment: Hi, thank you! This is a good start, i see the code, but my problem is to draw an image before Textbox.

Comment: My problem is that in the bound that PaintArgs give me,
it does not include the space used for the image before the textbox.

Comment: Have you tried to Paint the Image directly on the Owner? Set the ImageIndex to the ControlHost: `(groupMenu as ToolStripControlHost).ImageIndex = 0;`, then subscribe to Paint event of the Owner: `groupMenu.Owner.Paint += (o, a) => { a.Graphics.DrawImage([Your defined list].Images[groupMenu.ImageIndex], 5, groupMenu.Bounds.Y + 2); };` `5` is the default left padding, `2` is the default top padding.

Comment: This, if you want to draw the Image inside the usual position in a MenuStrip / ContextMenuStrip. If you want to draw it inside the ToolStripItem instead, set its Padding.Left to the `Image.Width + 4` and subscribe to the Paint event of the Item, to draw an Image on the left of the TextBox. It's not exactly clear from that code where you want to show the Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a direct answer to your question, the `ToolStripTextBox` doesn't have in its inheritance tree the `ToolStripMenuItem` so you can't deal with it in the exact same way.

To assign images to items like `ToolStripTextBox`, `ToolStripComboBox`, and `ToolStripDropDownItem`:

1. Override the hidden `Image` property and reverse the attributes to make it visible and accessible again. You will find it in the Properties window to assign an image. Or through the code.
2. Override the `OnParentChanged` method to subscribe to the parent's Paint event. The type of the parent of both `ContextMenuStrip` and a `MenuStrip` drop down is  `ToolStripDropDownMenu`.
3. Define the rectangle of the image and draw it.

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
using System.Drawing;

[DesignerCategory("ToolStrip"),
ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]
public class ToolStripSpringTextBox : ToolStripTextBox
{
    public ToolStripSpringTextBox() : base() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// The image that will be displayed on the item.
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true),
        EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
        Category("Appearance"),
        Description("The image associated with the object.")]
    public override Image Image { get => base.Image; set => base.Image = value; }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(ToolStrip oldParent, ToolStrip newParent)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(oldParent, newParent);

        if (newParent != null && newParent is ToolStripDropDownMenu)
        {
            newParent.Paint -= new PaintEventHandler(OnParentPaint);
            newParent.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(OnParentPaint);
        }

        if (oldParent != null)
            oldParent.Paint -= new PaintEventHandler(OnParentPaint);
    }

    private void OnParentPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Image is null || 
            (sender is ContextMenuStrip cmnu &&
            !cmnu.ShowImageMargin && !cmnu.ShowCheckMargin))
            return;

        var sz = Image.Size;
        var r = new Rectangle((Bounds.X - sz.Width - 7) / 2,
            (Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2 + Bounds.Y, sz.Width, sz.Height);

        if (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
            r.X = Bounds.Right + r.Width - ContentRectangle.X;

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, r);
    }
}
```

[image: MenuStrip]  [image: MenuStrip2]

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is the best Way to to this.

Comment: Before this i have found solution abot custom ContextMenuStrip. But your approach is better. Thanks again.